# Has anyone got the transparent MQTT gateway running in Azure IoT Edge?

Tags: mqtt, azure, edge

One of the main purposes of IoT Edge is to localize the computation
of the steady state (normal conditions) to the edge rather than in the
cloud.

Has anyone got Azure IoT Edge working as a "transparent" gateway
as detailed at

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-as-gateway#patterns

with standard protocols (MQTT, AMQP) rather than the proprietary SDK?

Answer (score 5):

We haven't been contacted by anyone who is using their own protocol client to connect to an Azure IoT Edge device working as a transparent gateway. That said, we do have many customers successfully using their own protocol client to connect to Azure IoT Hub. For these devices, connecting to an Edge device instead of IoT Hub should just require the installation of a couple certs, as detailed in [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-transparent-gateway-linux).

I'll also point out that the Client SDK provided by Microsoft is not proprietary. The SDKs are [open sourced on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks) and speak standard versions of MQTT, AMQP, or HTTP.

We're trying to focus our public support to bugs on our [GitHub issues page](http://www.github.com/azure/iotedge/issues) and questions in StackOverflow with the tag #azure-iot-edge. In the future you'll get a faster response in one of those forums. We have a devs continuously monitoring those issues.

Comment: Welcome aboard. We look forward to your participation. I am sure that you can be of help to many here.